# Split a rectangle like a mosaic

Tags: math, recursion, geometry, rectangles, divide

I try since yesterday to build a function which divide a rectangle like this :

n = 1

```
 ____________
|            |
|____________|
```

n = 2

```
 ____________
|____________|
|____________|
```

n = 3

```
 ____________
|______|_____|
|____________|
```

n = 4

```
 ____________
|______|_____|
|______|_____|
```

n = 5

```
 ____________
|__ |__|_____|
|______|_____|
```

I've search but not found any algorithm name.
At the end I want something like an array with the (x, y, Long, larg) of each rectangle.
I think it's something recursive with just some divisions by 2 but... I haven't found any solution of my problem.
So if you have just some tips for me (not an entire code) I will really appreciate that.

Sorry if my English is bad, if you want some precision don't hesitate.

Raph.

EDIT :

n = 5 is more like that :

```
    ____________
   |______|     |
   |______|_____|
   |______|_____|
```

EDIT 2 : Here is the code I did working until 8 separations

```
PROCEDURE TrouveCoordsV2(nImages is int, nNoEcran is int)
listeEcran is string = SysListScreen()
tabNoms is array of strings = StringSplit(listeEcran,CR)
tabResolutionInt is array of strings = StringSplit(SysScreenResolution(tabNoms[nNoEcran]), TAB)
tabResolutionEcran is array of int
dimensionsEcran is array of int
FOR i = 1 TO 2
    ArrayAdd(dimensionsEcran, Val(tabResolutionInt[i]))
END
ArrayAdd(tabResolutionEcran, TrouvePositionEcranX(nNoEcran, SysScreenRectangle()))
ArrayAdd(tabResolutionEcran, 0)
ArrayAdd(tabResolutionEcran, dimensionsEcran)
    INTERNAL PROCEDURE CalculResolution(n is int, resolution is array of int)
        tabResultat is array of arrays of int = []
        nLongueur is int = RoundDown(resolution[3]/2)
        nLargeur is int = RoundDown(resolution[4]/2)
        resHG, resHD, resBG, resBD, resHL, resBL are arrays of int
        resHG = [resolution[1], resolution[2], nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resHD = [resolution[1]+nLongueur, resolution[2], nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resBG = [resolution[1], resolution[2]+nLargeur, nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resBD = [resolution[1]+nLongueur, resolution[2]+nLargeur, nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resHL = [resolution[1], resolution[2], resolution[3], nLargeur]
        resBL = [resolution[1], resolution[2]+nLargeur, resolution[3], nLargeur]
        SWITCH n
            CASE 1
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resolution)
                RESULT tabResultat
            CASE 2
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resHL)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resBL)
                RESULT tabResultat
            CASE 3
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resHL)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resBG)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resBD)
                RESULT tabResultat
            CASE 4
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resHG)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resHD)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resBG)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, resBD)
                RESULT tabResultat
            CASE >4
                mod is int = modulo(n, 4)

                SWITCH mod
                    CASE 0
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-6, resHG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-6, resHD))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-6, resBG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-6, resBD))
                        RESULT tabResultat
                    CASE 1
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-5, resHG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-5, resHD))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-5, resBG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-3, resBD))
                        RESULT tabResultat
                    CASE 2
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-6, resHG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-6, resHD))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-4, resBG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-4, resBD))
                        RESULT tabResultat
                    CASE 3
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-7, resHG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-5, resHD))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-5, resBG))
                        ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(n-5, resBD))
                        RESULT tabResultat
                    OTHER CASE
                        Info("Une erreur inattendue est survenue au niveau de l'affichage des fenetres")
                END

            CASE <=0
                RESULT resolution
            OTHER CASE
                Info("Une erreur inattendue est survenue au niveau de l'affichage des fenetres")        
        END
    END
IF nImages > 8 THEN
    Info("Certaines aides n'ont pas pu êtres affichées")
    nImages = 8
END
RESULT CalculResolution(nImages,tabResolutionEcran)
```

I will try to find a solution for n separations.
If you want me to explain my code tell me because in WinDev comments are in a weird yellow background and give me an headache...
So I translate it partially in English for you.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day

Raph.

Comment: can you elaborate this (x, y, Long, larg). I meant the meaning of them

Comment: x and y are the top left coordinates of a subrectangle and sorry I write it in French, Long is the length and Larg is the width of this subrectangle, it's some infos for display windows on a screen

Comment: depending on the place where we divide, x,y can be changed. Is there a pattern of dividing?

Comment: I don't really understand your question but the pattern is like: you have a rectangle, you divide horizontally then you divide vertically the first subrect and then you divide the second one vertically too

Comment: I do not know WinDev so I can't say much about the code. Your second example printout for `n=5`has only 4 small rectangles, not 5. I do not understand what you mean by "dimensions" in your results for 5 and 8. If you use my algorithm you should find that 5 is prime, so use 4 and split a rectangle, and 8 can only be factored as 1x8 and 2x4.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. I've almost find a solution so I will post-it this afternoon or tomorrow. Dimensions is more Rectangle sizes. Thank you (I correct my second example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string :- "Hello world"

I find a working solution here is the code

```
PROCEDURE TrouveCoordsV2(nImages is int, nNoEcran is int)
listeEcran is string = SysListScreen()
tabNoms is array of strings = StringSplit(listeEcran,CR)
tabResolutionInt is array of strings = StringSplit(SysScreenResolution(tabNoms[nNoEcran]), TAB)
tabResolutionEcran is array of int
dimensionsEcran is array of int
FOR i = 1 TO 2
    ArrayAdd(dimensionsEcran, Val(tabResolutionInt[i]))
END
ArrayAdd(tabResolutionEcran, TrouvePositionEcranX(nNoEcran, SysScreenRectangle()))
ArrayAdd(tabResolutionEcran, 0)
ArrayAdd(tabResolutionEcran, dimensionsEcran)
    INTERNAL PROCEDURE CalculResolution(n is int, resolution is array of int)
        tabResultat is array of arrays of int = []
        nLongueur is int = RoundDown(resolution[3]/2)
        nLargeur is int = RoundDown(resolution[4]/2)
        resHG, resHD, resBG, resBD, resHL, resBL are arrays of int
        resHG = [resolution[1], resolution[2], nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resHD = [resolution[1]+nLongueur, resolution[2], nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resBG = [resolution[1], resolution[2]+nLargeur, nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resBD = [resolution[1]+nLongueur, resolution[2]+nLargeur, nLongueur, nLargeur]
        resHL = [resolution[1], resolution[2], resolution[3], nLargeur]
        resBL = [resolution[1], resolution[2]+nLargeur, resolution[3], nLargeur]
        IF n=1
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resolution)
        ELSE IF n=2
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resBL)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resHL)
        ELSE IF n=3
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resBD)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resBG)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resHL)
        ELSE IF n=4
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resBD)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resBG)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resHD)
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat,resHG)
        ELSE IF n>4
            tabNbImages is array of int = NbFenetresParEcrans(n,4)
            tabResolutions is array of arrays of int 
            ArrayAdd(tabResolutions,resBD)
            ArrayAdd(tabResolutions,resBG)
            ArrayAdd(tabResolutions,resHD)
            ArrayAdd(tabResolutions,resHG)
            FOR i = 1 TO 4
                ArrayAdd(tabResultat, CalculResolution(tabNbImages[i], tabResolutions[i]))
            END
        END
        RESULT tabResultat
    END
RESULT CalculResolution(nImages,tabResolutionEcran)
```

And there is the "NbFenetresParEcrans" function

```
PROCEDURE NbFenetresParEcrans(nNbFichiers is int, nNbEcrans is int)
tabFenetres is array of int = []
nDivision is int
nFichiersRestants is int = nNbFichiers
i is int = nNbEcrans
WHILE i > 0
    nDivision = RoundUp(nFichiersRestants/i)
    ArrayAdd(tabFenetres, nDivision)
    nFichiersRestants -= nDivision
    i--
END
RESULT tabFenetres
```

Thanks all for your help if you want precision I can give you.

Have a nice day and comments in WinDev give you good headache (:

Answer (score 0):

You give no code or algorithm, and just ask for "some tips," so I'll just give a broad idea here. If you want me to expand on this idea, show more work of your own.

If your value of `n`, the number of small rectangles, is a composite number (let's say `n = a * b`), then you could easily make a big rectangle with sides `a` and `b` that will have `n` small rectangles.

If `n` is prime and greater than 3, then `n-1` is composite. You could make a big rectangle with `n-1` little rectangles, then split one of the small rectangles into to smaller rectangles. That's basically what you did in your examples for `n=3` and `n=5`.

Note that no recursion is required. Of course, another possibility is just to draw a rectangle of size `1` by `n`, but that is not close to a square. If an additional goal is to get as close to a square as possible, then for composite `n` in my method you have the additional problem of finding `a` and `b` as close to each other as possible. (For example, if `n` is 12, you probably want `a=4` and `b=3` rather than `a=2` and `b=6`.) I'll leave that problem to you.

Comment: Yes I write an algorithm but it's WinDev and I write it in French so not very appropriate. Thank you for your help I will work on this this afternoon and I will show you what I do (I just need to find the translation function on the software). Thank you Mr. Daulton

Comment: This is a brilliant idea!